# TextWrapped Label breaks Layout Option FillAndExpand in StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, word-wrap

I'm having a cell view with nested `StackLayout`s, there's one label that will be wrapped if the text is long, which is the desired behaviour. However, the wrap breaks the `LayoutOptions` set to (basically) all parent views resulting in a gray gap on the right hand side.

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Gray" Margin="0,30,0,0">
        <BoxView
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            BackgroundColor="#EEBB00"
            WidthRequest="100"
        />
        <StackLayout
            BackgroundColor="#CC4400"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        >
            <BoxView
                BackgroundColor="Green"
                HeightRequest="10"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            />
            <Label
                FontSize="16"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="Name that is toolongandwillbewrapped"
            />
            <StackLayout
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="Blue"
            >
                <Label
                    FontSize="13"
                    Text="Left"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                />
                <Label
                    FontSize="13"
                    Text="Right"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="End"
                />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

The resulting views are:

[image: Right-hand label's text wrap breaks the <code>FillAndExpand</code>]
[image: Short text is ok]

So I can tell why this is happening, but well, of course I don't like it. The expected behaviour is for the right-hand-side stacklayout to expand all the way to the right. I've tried various ways to circumvent this and would not be here if I had succeeded. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a bug in Xamarin.Forms (probably, iOS-only).

- [Bugzilla #28650](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28650)
- [Bugzilla #31128](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31128)
- [Bugzilla #33841](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33841)

The workaround in that case is using `Grid` instead of `StackLayout` : http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/152969/#Comment_152969